# CSS content script issue in Google Chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am creating a simple Chrome extension that blocks the ["Google" logo image](https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) on the [Google homepage](http://www.google.com) using a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). I followed the directions on the content-script page, but it still does not seem to be working. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**: I have tested it with other website like [flickr.com](http://www.flickr.com) and it works perfectly. I've also searched through the Google homepage CSS and cannot figure out which CSS rule is overriding my CSS. Any ideas? How can I make a stronger CSS injection so that no other CSS can override mine?

---

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Google Logo Blocker",
  "description": "This extension blocks the Google logo image.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://www.google.com/"],
     "css": ["blocker.css"]
   }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

**blocker.css**:

```
img {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me.  You are using straight USA Google, not an international version, right?

Just in case, change your `matches` to:

```
"matches": ["http://*.google.com/", "https://*.google.com/"],
```

And target the logo more directly.  This will work in most cases:

```
#hplogo {
    display: none !important;
}
```

---

---

For full-on, international Google support, change the `content_scripts` portion of your manifest to:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches":          ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "include_globs":    ["http://*.google.*/*", "https://*.google.*/*"],
    "css":              ["blocker.css"]
} ],
```

Optionally also using `exclude_matches` and/or `exclude_globs` as desired.

---

---

If it still doesn't work, state the usual:

1. **Exact** URL
2. Chrome version
3. OS
4. Other extensions active

Comment: Although you address it, its important to highlight that google redirects you to your local domain. For example if I hit `http://google.com`, it redirects `https://google.co.in`

Comment: @juzerali, true and I added more i18n to the answer.  The OP's profile has him in the USA, though.

Comment: @BrockAdams: `"http://*.google.*/*"` domains are not supported in match patterns, check [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/chromium-extensions/njkDwIF7WDc/YxfwQLNeMD0J)

Comment: @Sudarshan, they're not in the match pattern, they're in the `include_globs`, where they **do** work.  See [the actual docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs) or just try it.

Comment: I feel this no longer works with recent versions of Chrome (i.e. 25.x). Who's with me?

Comment: @ferik, I just tested this; it still works perfectly in Chrome `26.0.1410.43 m` (latest release).  If you have a situation where it doesn't appear to work, open a new question and give details.

Answer (score 1):

It is  `<img>` tag in modern version and  is a `<div>` tag with background image for international version. Regardless, of the differences they bear same `id = hplogo`, so this can work for you.

[**Click for Larger Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok3hs.png)

[image]

Use

```
#hplogo{
       display:none !important;
}
```

it will remove google Logo.

Comment: No, it is an image tag on (most) layouts.  However, it does have the id `hplogo`.

Comment: @BrockAdams: i checked `google.co.in` and `google.de`, it is a div tag here

Comment: `<div dir="ltr" title="Google" align="left" id="hplogo" onload="window.lol&amp;&amp;lol()" style="background:url(images/srpr/logo3w.png) no-repeat;background-size:275px 95px;height:95px;width:275px"><div nowrap="nowrap" style="color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;position:relative;left:214px;top:70px">Deutschland</div></div>` code of Home Page

Comment: Notice that his match is for **`http://www.google.com/`**, ***not*** an international version.  For the more modern layouts, the logo is: `<img width="275" height="95" style="padding-top:112px" onload="window.lol&amp;&amp;lol()" id="hplogo" src="/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Google">`

Comment: But your CSS should work, irregardless, since it goes off id (which *seems* to be constant) not tag type.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Thanks for making aware of modern version, i will edit my answer accordingly.